# Azure DevOps YAML Pipelines prevent newer runs if old one queued

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I have a pipeline with a number of stages, e.g.:

```
Canary -> Dev -> UAT -> Prod
```

For each stage we have approvals set so a team member has to allow a build to proceed to the next stage. Sometimes we have long periods between stages being approved (e.g. someone needs to do some testing and feedback outside of devops we can proceed), therefore it can be hard to remember we have an old run pending approval unless we specifically check - which is prone to human error.

But if I have one build say queued at UAT awaiting push to production how can I prevent a second run which includes the changes from the first run (as they are both running off master) being allowed to proceeded.

E.g. I need newer jobs to be aware of older runs still pending approval to proceed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no default way to prevent newer runs if old one queued, but you can try the following workaround:

You could add a script in the pipeline to check `state` of the latest pipeline run. If the `state` is `inProgress`, cancel the build. If the `state` is `completed`, proceed the build.

You should use [Runs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) api to get `state` of the latest pipeline run. The script looks like:

```
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$org/$projectName/_apis/pipelines/$pipelineid/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$latestrun = $result.value.state[0]
Write-Host  "$latestrun"
```

Then you could refer the following case to cancel the build if `$latestrun` is `inProgress`:
[Is it possible to cancel a Azure DevOps pipeline Job programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62044055/is-it-possible-to-cancel-a-azure-devops-pipeline-job-programmatically)

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?