# how to brake the pipeline if the nuget package is not up to date?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline at azure DevOps with the following tasks:

-Pack .net core
-check nuget dependencies
-publish artifact

The first task packs the nuget and the second one checks if their versions and shows the existent last version.

What I need to do is that the pipeline stop in case the nuget packages are not up-to-date.

Any idea how I could set it up?

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, you could define a global variable about your current nuget package latest version, also your current nuget package version.

Create two variable as `LastVersion` and `NewVersion` variable.

[image]

`LastVersion` is the last version of your nuget package on the package source, you should search for it and give a value for it.

`NewVersion` is the current nuget version you want to pack.

After that, use a powershell task with the condition of `'$(LastVersion)'-eq '$(NewVersion)'` to cancel the job. You can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62044055/is-it-possible-to-cancel-a-azure-devops-pipeline-job-programmatically) about the steps.

Or you could use `exit 1` under powershell task with the below command to cancel this:

```
 #if LastVersion is the same as NewVersion, cancel the job       
 if( '$(LastVersion)' -eq '$(NewVersion)')
 {
   exit 1
 }
 else
 {
  exit 0
 }
```

Comment: Thank's for your suggestion, but I don't think it covers de whole problem, since  I have several packages and each one of them got different versions. 
I actually have found a task called "Nukeeper"  that seems to cover this problem, however I've got a error of "Oauth missing". The problem is that there isn' any slot to fill with the token information.

Comment: that is an easy workaround. And your requirements are quite complex and might not meet your expectations. Also, I could not find Nukeeper task. Could you try some steps about that?